# Power Query: how to remove diacritic/accent symbols from text

Tags: function, text, powerbi, powerquery, diacritics

How to remove **diacritic**/**accent** symbols from text in `Power Bi` / `Power Query` ?

Example:

```
Convert this: 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž'
to this:      'AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please create & try the following function:

```
= (textToConvert) =>
let 
    textBinary = Text.ToBinary  (textToConvert,              1251 ),
    textASCII  = Text.FromBinary(textBinary   , TextEncoding.Ascii)
in    
    textASCII
```

[image: Diacritic symbols removal example]

Comment: Why encoding type `1251`?  Why don't other encodings work?  (eg `Utf8`, `Windows` (which is 1252), etc). I believe `Utf8` => `ASCII` works in `R`.